# Next Js 13 routing

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

how I can add dynamicly and remove query parameter with Next Js useRouter from "next/navigation" with App Routing?
I need add filter to query, such as add `filters=219,213` with `.../hotels?id=123&type=hotel`

I tried router replace to add new query params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use `useSearchParams` and `usePathname` to get `query` and `pathname`. You can also use `router.replace` if you want to update existing history record instead of adding new one.

```
'use client'

import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Page() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const router = useRouter()

  const updateQuery = () => {
    const newUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString())
    newUrlParams.set('filters', ['219', '213'].join(','))
    router.push(`${pathname}?${newUrlParams}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={updateQuery}>Update filter</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```